# Can a saved game be carried over between editions?

Tags: fallout-4, ps4

I was hoping to buy a copy of Fallout 4 GOTY (Game of the Year Edition), and I wanted to know if my save states and data would carry over from my original copy of Fallout 4, or if I had to start a new game.
To be clear, I am playing on Playstation 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**GOTY = Fallout 4 + Season Pass**

Fallout 4 in the GOTY edition is the exact same game as in any other edition.
The GOTY edition just adds the official DLC - Automatron, Wasteland Workshop, Far Harbor, Contraptions Workshop, Vault-Tec Workshop, and Nuka World - in the form of the Season Pass.

This all means that nothing really changes: **it just adds the DLC you didn't own yet to the base game, and should (in theory) blend in seamlessly with your current game.**

Comment: You are welcome! Do you mind accepting this answer, and upvoting it if deemed worthy?

Comment: OK. I've since bought the game and it works fine. thanks again.